# HTML and CSS: fix misbehaving list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I need help in fixing a 2-column list.

The problem is that the right column intrudes into the left one if more than single line used.

Another trouble is that if left column has more than one line, the content inside of the right column will appear at the bottom.

The separating line between columns also acts strange with more than 1 line (see the examples below).

Please note, I'd like to keep "Title" and "Description" columns in separate HTML-tags (at least one of them inside a tag), because I need this for Responsive CSS layout.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none!important;
}
ul.my-list>li {
  width: 550px!important;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  background: 0 0;
  border-radius: 0!important;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #EEE;
}
ul.my-list>li span {
  width: 140px;
  border-right: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 0;
  line-height: 38px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="my-list">
  <li><span>Title</span>Description. Not too many words – displays well.</li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<ul class="my-list">
  <li><span>Title</span>Description. More words – this goes wrong. Really wrong. Seriously...At least the "Description" column should not intrude into the "Title" column.</li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<ul class="my-list">
  <li><span>Title with many words acts weird too</span>Description. How to fix the "Description" column, so it would start from the top side, not from the bottom?</li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem, mostly by creating two separated `<span>` tags for each of the columns and using `display: inline-flex;` for the whole `<li>` tag.

The solution is CSS Responsive Layout friendly and works with all window sizes.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tay06de4/4/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```css
ul.my-list>li span {
  float:left;
  }

ul.my-list>li {
  min-height: 80px;
  
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, works better now. However, with 3 lines of text, the right column still intrudes into the left one. And the border line (separating the columns) is still limited to one-line height. Any help? http://jsfiddle.net/tay06de4/3/